# How to get user (Info Account player) in Facebook Instant Game from unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having problems with my Instant game Facebook. I use `FB.Init ()` to create connections and get information. It works fine when I run on unity but when building `Webgl` and uploading Instant Game `FB.Init ()` My seems to be inactive, I tried checking it but didn't get any changes inside.

```
void Start() {
    FB.Init(setInit, onHideUnity);
}

private void setInit() {
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        nameDo.text = "Name 5";
        Debug.Log("Set init loggedIn");
    } else {
        nameDo.text = "Name 4";
        Debug.Log("Set init not loggedIn");
        login();
    }
}

private void onHideUnity(bool isShowUnity) {
    if (isShowUnity) {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    } else {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question in general is unclear, in fact you don't even ask a question. Please refresh about [ask] good questions, as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I think you have to use a different api key. Also, you might need to set a domain in FB (it was quite a while ago since I last used fb, but that might be good places to start checking).